# WPF Window Not Showing Transparency Correctly

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-interface, window

TI'm having some trouble getting my Window to be Transparent.

The Window is defined below:

```
<Window x:Class="HKC.Desktop.Views.UserInterfaces.RemoteKeypad"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Closing="Window_Close"
        KeyDown="RemoteKeypad_KeyDown"
        KeyUp="RemoteKeypad_KeyUp" MouseDown="OnMouseDown_Event"
        Title="Title"  Width="325" Height="370"
        ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"  WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency="True" Background="Transparent">
```

I then have a border defined to give a curved edge to the Window, with a Grid inside for layout purposes:

```
<Border CornerRadius="20" Background="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
     <Border.Effect>
          <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="6" ShadowDepth="3" Color="#484948" />
     </Border.Effect>
     <Grid Background="Transparent" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
          ....
     </Grid>
</Border>
</Window>
```

For some reason, the first time that I open the window the background is not transparent

[image]

However, If I click away from the Window, back back on it, the transparency is working as expected.

Comment: are you on windows-xp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was with an external tool for adding Drop Shadows to elements.